# How to assign data type to a parameter and if that data type is not same as i assigned raise an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright, so i was coding when i stumbled upon a problem:

```
def myFunction(string):
    print(string + "test")
```

Now, when i put a string, it runs perfectly fine. But, when i put in an int:

```
myFunction(str(1)):
```

It still works? Now, i know i put a `str()` function to the "1" value. But, if i wanted to have a function that takes in a parameter with the data type string, and type an integer value to that parameter, it still works. How can i do it?

Comment: does this help? https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/

Comment: Python is a dynamically typed language. If you want to verify the types of some parameter, you have to manually do this, or use some third-party library that does it already

Comment: When you pass `str(1)` into a function you're passing a _string_ into it, not an integer. `str(1)` returns the string `"1"`. But as juanpa.arrivillaga says Python is not statically typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), which allows `myFunction` to concatenate a type other than a string, with a string:

```py
def myFunction(o: object):
    print(f'{o}test')
```

Or, even better yet:

```py
def myFunction(o: object):
    print(o, 'test', sep='')
```

Then the desired call should work without needing to wrap the value in `str()` explicitly:

```
>>> myFunction(1)
1test
```

If you prefer to be more explicit, I'd suggest changing it like below; what this does is call `str(o)` internally, only it looks a bit nicer.

```py
def myFunction(o: object):
    print(f'{o!s}test')
```

Comment: this does work, but i leaned how to do it before you posted the comment. Thank you though!

Comment: No problem! Hope I was able to clarify on something in particular, at least.